Filtering a CTE with 172 rows with another with 72 rows is taking a very long time
Here is my code:
with 
       
      pairs as 
(
select distinct team_info."number" as "team_number", aic_info."name" as aic_name,
      aic_assets."IMEI" as parent_imei, team_assets ."IMEI" as child_imei, 0 as count, ucs.name as "uc_name", tehsils.name as "tehsil_name", districts.name as "district_name", provinces.name as "province_name"
    from campaign_staff team  
      left join campaign_staff_info team_info on team."ID" = team_info."campaignStaffID" and team_info.date = (select max(date) from campaign_staff_info team_info2 where team_info2."campaignStaffID" = team_info."campaignStaffID" and team_info2.date<='2024-05-04')
      left join campaign_staff aic on team."parentID" = aic."ID" 
      left join campaign_staff_info aic_info on aic."ID" = aic_info."campaignStaffID" and aic_info.date = (select max(date) from campaign_staff_info aic_info2 where aic_info2."campaignStaffID" = aic_info."campaignStaffID" and aic_info2.date<='2024-05-04')
      left join campaign_staff_assets team_staff_assets on team_staff_assets."campaignStaffID" = team."ID" and team_staff_assets."date" = (select max(date) from campaign_staff_assets cs2 where cs2."campaignStaffID"= team_staff_assets."campaignStaffID" and cs2.date<='2024-05-04')
      left join campaign_staff_assets aic_staff_assets on aic_staff_assets."campaignStaffID" = aic."ID" and aic_staff_assets."date" = (select max(date) from campaign_staff_assets cs2 where cs2."campaignStaffID"= aic_staff_assets."campaignStaffID" and cs2.date<='2024-05-04')
      left join assets team_assets on team_assets."ID" = team_staff_assets."assetID"
      left join assets aic_assets on aic_assets."ID" = aic_staff_assets."assetID"
      left join campaign_asset_status aic_cas on aic_cas."campaignStaffID" = aic."ID" and aic_cas.date = (select max(date) from campaign_asset_status aic_cas_tmp where aic_cas_tmp.date <= '2024-05-04' and aic_cas_tmp."campaignStaffID" = aic_cas."campaignStaffID")
      left join campaign_asset_status team_cas on team_cas."campaignStaffID" = team."ID" and team_cas.date = (select max(date) from campaign_asset_status team_cas_tmp where team_cas_tmp.date <= '2024-05-04' and team_cas_tmp."campaignStaffID" = team_cas."campaignStaffID")
    left join area ucs on team."campaignScopeID" = ucs."ID"
    left join area tehsils on ucs."parentID" = tehsils."ID"
    left join area districts on tehsils."parentID" = districts."ID"
    left join area provinces on districts."parentID" = provinces."ID"
    where 
      team."staffTypeID" = 'acf0cc70-7c92-474d-82af-f37494f94c09' -- Team ID 
      and aic."staffTypeID" = '93313048-4e75-4e91-9bcd-44897a6df7c7' -- AIC ID
      and team."parentID" = aic."ID"
      and (aic_cas.date is null or (aic_cas.status not in ('Inactive', 'DeployedWoPhone') and aic_cas.date = (select max(date) from campaign_asset_status aic_cas_tmp where aic_cas_tmp.date <= '2024-05-04' and aic_cas_tmp."campaignStaffID" = aic_cas."campaignStaffID")))
      and (team_cas.date is null or (team_cas.status not in ('Inactive', 'DeployedWoPhone') and team_cas.date = (select max(date) from campaign_asset_status team_cas_tmp where team_cas_tmp.date <= '2024-05-04' and team_cas_tmp."campaignStaffID" = team_cas."campaignStaffID"))) 
    and ((ucs."ID" = '00b78578-1e82-492a-b5de-1d50071fe4cb') or (tehsils."ID" = '00b78578-1e82-492a-b5de-1d50071fe4cb') or (districts."ID" = '00b78578-1e82-492a-b5de-1d50071fe4cb') or (provinces."ID" = '00b78578-1e82-492a-b5de-1d50071fe4cb'))
    and (aic."removedDate" is null or aic."removedDate"> '2024-05-04'::date) 
    and (team."removedDate" is null or team."removedDate"> '2024-05-04'::date)
    order by aic_assets."IMEI"
    
)
--
,

  
       ping as ( -- ================= SELECTING JOINED data with join conditions -- ================= -- ================= -- ================= -- ================= -- ================= 
        select 
          u."imei" as u_imei, 
          a."imei" as a_imei, 
          u.t as u_ping_time, 
          a.t as a_ping_time, 
          u_ping_id, 
          a_ping_id 
        from 

(-- ================= SELECTING Parent INFO [imei, geom, generatedAt, pingID] -- ================= -- ================= -- ================= -- ================= -- ================= 
            select 
              p.imei, 
              p."geoJson" as geom,
              --st_transform(p."geoJson", 32643) as geom, 
              "generatedAt" as t, 
              p."ID" as u_ping_id 
            from 
              campaign_pings p 
            
              
              where --"createdAt"::date = '2024-05-04'--'2024-05-04'
              
              "generatedAt"+ interval '5 hours' between '2024-05-04 06:00:00 ' and '2024-05-04 06:30:00'  
                       
              and 
              
              p.imei in (
                select 
                  assets."IMEI" 
                from 
                  campaign_staff staff 
                  left join campaign_staff_info csi on csi."campaignStaffID"=staff."ID" and csi."date" = (select max(date) from campaign_staff_info csi2 where csi2."campaignStaffID" = csi."campaignStaffID" and csi2.date <= '2024-05-04')
                  left join campaign_staff_assets csa on csa."campaignStaffID" = staff."ID" and csa."date" = (select max(date) from campaign_staff_assets cs2 where cs2."campaignStaffID"= csa."campaignStaffID" and cs2.date<='2024-05-04')
                  left join campaign_area_assets caa on caa."assetID" = csa."assetID" 
                  and caa."campaignScopeAreaID" = csa."campaignScopeID" 
                  left join assets assets on assets."ID" = caa."assetID" 
                  left join staff_type staff_type ON staff_type."ID" = staff."staffTypeID"
                  left join campaign_asset_status cas  on cas."campaignStaffID" = staff."ID" and cas."date" = (select max(date) from campaign_asset_status cas2 where cas2."campaignStaffID"= cas."campaignStaffID" and cas2.date<='2024-05-04')
                  left join campaign_scope cs on cs."areaID" = caa."campaignScopeAreaID"
                  where 
                  caa."campaignScopeAreaID" = '00b78578-1e82-492a-b5de-1d50071fe4cb' --'00b78578-1e82-492a-b5de-1d50071fe4cb' 
                  and assets."IMEI" is not null 
                  and staff_type."ID" = '93313048-4e75-4e91-9bcd-44897a6df7c7' -- AIC ID
                  and (cas.status is null or cas.status  <> 'DeployedWoPhone')
                  and ((csi.number is null) or (csi.number <> '0'))
                  and '2024-05-04' between cs."campaignStartDate" and cs."catchupEndDate"  
              )
          ) u 
          inner join ( -- ================= SELECTING child INFO [imei, geom, generatedAt, pingID] -- ================= -- ================= -- ================= -- ================= -- ================= 
            SELECT 
              p.imei, 
              p."ID" as a_ping_id, 
              p."geoJson" as geom,
              --st_transform(p."geoJson", 32643) as geom, 
              "generatedAt" as t 
            FROM 
              campaign_pings p 
              
              where --"createdAt"::date = '2024-05-04' --'2024-05-04'
              
              "generatedAt"+ interval '5 hours' between '2024-05-04 06:00:00 ' and '2024-05-04 06:30:00'
              
              and 
                            
              p.imei in (
                select 
                  assets."IMEI" 
                from 
                  campaign_staff staff 
                  left join campaign_staff_assets csa on csa."campaignStaffID" = staff."ID" and csa."date" = (select max(date) from campaign_staff_assets cs2 where cs2."campaignStaffID"= csa."campaignStaffID" and cs2.date<='2024-05-04')
                  left join campaign_area_assets caa on caa."assetID" = csa."assetID" 
                  and caa."campaignScopeAreaID" = csa."campaignScopeID" 
                  left join assets assets on assets."ID" = caa."assetID" 
                  left join staff_type staff_type ON staff_type."ID" = staff."staffTypeID"
                  left join campaign_asset_status cas  on cas."campaignStaffID" = staff."ID" and cas."date" = (select max(date) from campaign_asset_status cas2 where cas2."campaignStaffID"= cas."campaignStaffID" and cas2.date<='2024-05-04')
                  left join campaign_scope cs on cs."areaID" = caa."campaignScopeAreaID"
                  
                  where 
                  
                  caa."campaignScopeAreaID" = '00b78578-1e82-492a-b5de-1d50071fe4cb' 
                  and assets."IMEI" is not null 
                  and staff_type."ID" = 'acf0cc70-7c92-474d-82af-f37494f94c09' -- Team ID
                  and (cas.status is null or cas.status  <> 'DeployedWoPhone')
                  and '2024-05-04' between cs."campaignStartDate" and cs."catchupEndDate"
                  
              )
          ) a on ST_DWithin(u."geom"::geography, a."geom"::geography, 30) 
          and a.t BETWEEN u.t - INTERVAL '30 seconds' 
          and u.t + INTERVAL '30 seconds' 
          where 
          a.imei is not null
      )

 



,
results AS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM ping
    JOIN pairs ON ping.u_imei = pairs.parent_imei AND ping.a_imei = pairs.child_imei
)

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM results;
  
  
  
 

My ping CTE only has 187 rows. My pairs CTE has only 72 rows. If I remove the results CTE, the query executes in a couple of seconds.
When I re-insert the results CTE, it keeps on going on for minutes without stopping, then I have to forcefully stop the query. I have tried various different strategies such as replacing the join with subquery IN etc. but it always gets stuck. I can not include the query plan here because of this website's posting limitation when it comes to total characters in a post.
Here is the query plan (https://codeshare.io/ApvQPp) - I could not paste the entire thing here, even as text, as the character limit was crossed.
The DDL of the campaign_pings table is:
PK_953f5825000b2b7d6583b3bd987  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "PK_953f5825000b2b7d6583b3bd987" ON public.campaign_pings USING btree ("ID")
campaing_pings_createdat_date   CREATE INDEX campaing_pings_createdat_date ON public.campaign_pings USING btree ((("createdAt")::date))
campaing_pings_generatedat_date CREATE INDEX campaing_pings_generatedat_date ON public.campaign_pings USING btree ((("generatedAt")::date))
cp_date_idx CREATE INDEX cp_date_idx ON public.campaign_pings USING btree ("generatedAt")
cp_geoJson_idx  CREATE INDEX "cp_geoJson_idx" ON public.campaign_pings USING gist ("geoJson")
cp_idx_createdat    CREATE INDEX cp_idx_createdat ON public.campaign_pings USING btree ("createdAt")
cp_imei_hash    CREATE INDEX cp_imei_hash ON public.campaign_pings USING hash (imei)
cp_imei_idx CREATE INDEX cp_imei_idx ON public.campaign_pings USING btree (imei)
cp_imeidate_idx CREATE INDEX cp_imeidate_idx ON public.campaign_pings USING btree ("generatedAt", imei)
gist_geog_cp_geojson    CREATE INDEX gist_geog_cp_geojson ON public.campaign_pings USING gist (geography("geoJson"))

 


Could you please share the results from explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) for this query and the DDL for all tables and indexes involved? (all in plain text)

@FrankHeikens I have shared that, thanks

Why do you join campaign_asset_status 10 times? And campaign_staff_assets 8 times? This doesn't look very efficient to me, nor to the database: subplans all over the place, database is kind of lost. I would start over again, without repeating tables in many joins. Not a single table is used just once.

The query is malformed. The predicate aic."staffTypeID" = ... defeats the outer join. Please fix the query -- either by removing the outer join, or the predicate -- before we try to optimize it.

@TheImpaler amazingly, if I run the pairs CTE (the one with the offensive logic) by itelf, it executes in less that one second!

The lines that appear contradictory to me are and left join campaign_staff aic on team."parentID" = aic."ID" and and team."parentID" = aic."ID", the latter being immediately below the line that The Impaler referenced. Like The Impaler wrote, one of those two lines should be deleted. Keep the left join if you want the result to include records without matching parents. Keep the other criterion (or replace the left join with an inner join) if you strictly want records with matching parents. It sounds like we're getting close to a solution for which we can write up an answer.

@SmellyCat but all that happens in the pairs CTE, which if I execute alone, it takes less than a second!

Please update it with the results from EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS). A plain EXPLAIN without the additional options is of very limited value for all but rudimentary optimization efforts. Keep in mind that SQL is a declarative language; i.e., a query expresses what, not how. PostgreSQL is free to rearrange the query into any semantically equivalent form. Some parts might not even execute if they don't contribute to the final result set. Removing parts of a query can significantly affect execution.
